Azure Functions Configuration Management without appsettings.json/local.settings.json
I'm working with Azure Functions and using a custom configuration approach without relying on appsettings.json. Instead, I'm using a folder named "config" to store environment-specific settings.
My current setup involves:
A Program.cs file that uses HostBuilder to configure the application.
A config folder containing files with no extensions, where each file represents an environment variable.
One such file is named "azure-bus-connection" and contains a secret value.
Here's my Program.cs code snippet:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        var configFolder = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "config");
        context.Configuration = builder.AddDirectory(configFolder).Build();
    })
    // ... rest of the configuration code ...


My function uses this configuration to set up a Service Bus connection:
[Function(nameof(MyWorker))]
public async Task MyWorker(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", nameof(MyRequest), Connection = "azure-bus-connection")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{
    var connectionString = configuration["azure-bus-connection"];
    // ... rest of the function code ...
}


I'm having trouble managing environment variables in this setup as my function does not recognize the secret added using AddDirectory. How can I ensure that sensitive information like the Azure Service Bus connection string is kept secure and not exposed in my code or logs but ?
Is there a recommended way to handle secret management in Azure Functions without using appsettings.json/local.settings.json or storing secrets directly in code?
Additional Context
I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker package.
I've configured Application Insights telemetry.
I'm using a custom middleware for global exception handling.
I've configured logging options to remove default Application Insights logger rules.
Any advice or best practices for managing secrets securely in Azure Functions with custom configuration would be greatly appreciated.
Addition to secrets my AKS deployment yaml file looks as follows:
template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ${PROJECT_SLUG}
    aadpodidbinding: ${PROJECT_SLUG}
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ${PROJECT_SLUG}
      image: ${PROJECT_IMAGE}
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: "/config"
          readOnly: true
      ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: ${PROJECT_SLUG}-config
  volumes:
    - name: secrets-store-inline
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: "${PROJECT_SLUG}"


Did you try using Azure Keyvault?

@PravallikaKV - yes I am using keyvault, but what I do is mount the configs please see the edit that has kubernetes.

To configure variable of application without using appsettings.json or local.settings.json, you can use either an .env file or Azure Key Vault.
   var connectionString = _configuration["azure-bus-connection"];
   _logger.LogInformation(connectionString);


Refer to this link to Create a function app without default storage secrets in its definition  using key vault.

First step is to create an .env file and define the environment variables within it:
azure-bus-connection=your_connection_string_here
sampath=your_connection_string_here

Add below  sample docker to build and push a Docker image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# For Azure Functions with .NET 8.0 isolated runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]

To build and run the Docker image, use below commands:
docker build -t hello .

docker run -e azure-bus-connection="Endpoint=sb://" -e sampath="Endpoint=sb://=" hello



I referred to this link to define environment variables for a container that runs in a Pod.

Login to Container registry using az acr login -n yourregistryname and push the image to registry using docker push imageName:tag

Use the above Repositories image in yml file of Kubernetes service .
Create Kubernetes service  and  Connect to it .
Below  YAML configuration file to create a Pod in Kubernetes with environment variables:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: azure-bus-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: azure-bus-container
    image: your-image-here  # Replace with your actual image, e.g., hello-world or any relevant image
    env:
    - name: azure-bus-connection
      value: "Endpoint=sb://"
    - name: sampath
      value: "Endpoint=sb://"

Save this file as azure-bus-pod.yaml to apply the configuration and create the Pod using below command :
kubectl apply -f azure-bus-pod.yaml



Next confirm that the Pod is running by using kubectl get pods -l purpose=demonstrate-envars and  then List the environment variables in the container by using
kubectl exec azure-bus-demo -- printenv


Use below command to Create and run a particular image in a pod
kubectl run azurebusdemo --image=sampath45.azurecr.io/hello:v1


